# Apple's speakhere project, different UI

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudioplayer

I am working on an app that is similar to apple's speakhere project for audio. the project itself has the AQLevelMeter showing a nice db meter, but I am looking to build one that shows db level but as a graph, and to keep on updating as the recording continues. Anyone done this before or can point me to sample projects close to what I am looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: Eddie, trying to do the same, still having problems putting SpeakHere code into Objective-C project (all those __bridges!). Did you succeed? Any other hints? Thanks, nobi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [core plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).  It is a static library that makes excellent graphs. They have a great website with sample code.  The one you are probably referring to would be their real time plot.  Hope this helps.